# What are $C^{1,1}$-manifolds

Tags: notation, manifolds

They are oviously a class of manifolds between $C^1$ and $C^2$ manifolds, but I cannot find a definition. They are of interest, because they have positive reach. Thanks in advance

Comment: They are manifolds with transition functions of class $C^{1,1}$. A function is of class $C^{1,1}$ if it is differentiable and if its differential is Lipschitz.